# setroubleshootd process after my multiprocess python application execution

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, redhat

I wrote a multiprocessing application in Python (python 2.7.3, RedHat7); I can observe that after each execution, the `setroubleshootd` process increasingly uses memory and CPUs.

I'm sure that my application doesn't leave zombie processes...

Some ideas about this trouble?

Thanks

Larry

Comment: Is your python program opening files?  It might be a permission problem.

Comment: Yes, it opens files in read mode. Then, it uses logging package to log, but I implemented a log handler for each process.

Comment: Does your program have permissions to read the files?